# Why codes seem keep ignoring conditions for my quant strategy when generating signals?

Tags: python

I have drafted below middle school strategy...

```
from matplotlib import pylab
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from backtesting import Backtest , Strategy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_excel("E:/usdcnh.xls")
print(df.columns)

class MovingAverageStrategy:
    def __init__(self, df, window_size, buy_threshold, sell_threshold, stop_loss, take_profit):
        self.df = df
        self.window_size = window_size
        self.buy_threshold = buy_threshold
        self.sell_threshold = sell_threshold

        self.stop_loss = stop_loss
        self.take_profit = take_profit

    def calculate_moving_average(self):
        self.df['MovingAverage'] = self.df['Close'].rolling(window=self.window_size).mean()

    def calculate_deviation(self):
        self.df['Deviation'] = self.df['Close'] - self.df['MovingAverage']

    def generate_signals(self):
        self.calculate_moving_average()
        self.calculate_deviation()

        self.df['Position'] = 0 
        self.df['Accu_Position'] = self.df['Position'] + self.df['Position'].shift(-1)
        self.df['Accu_Position'].iloc[-1] = self.df['Position'].iloc[-1]

        self.df['Buy_Condition'] = (self.df['Deviation'] <= self.buy_threshold) & (self.df['Accu_Position'] == 0)
        self.df['Buy_Signal'] = np.where(self.df['Buy_Condition'], 1, 0)
        self.df['Sell_Condition'] = (self.df['Deviation'] >= self.sell_threshold) & (self.df['Accu_Position'] == 0)
        self.df['Sell_Signal'] = np.where(self.df['Sell_Condition'] , -1, 0)

        self.df['EntryPrice'] = np.where((self.df['Buy_Signal']!=0) | (self.df['Sell_Signal']!=0), self.df['Close'], 0)
        self.df['EntryPriceRecord'] = np.where(self.df['EntryPrice']!=0, self.df['EntryPrice'], self.df['EntryPrice'].shift(-1)) 
        self.df['PriceChange'] = self.df['Close'] - self.df['EntryPriceRecord']

        self.df['StopLoss_Signal'] = 0  
        stop_loss_condition = ((self.df['Accu_Position'] == 1) & (self.df['PriceChange'] <= -self.stop_loss)) | ((self.df['Accu_Position'] == -1) & (self.df['PriceChange'] >= self.stop_loss))
        self.df.loc[stop_loss_condition, 'StopLoss_Signal'] = -self.df['Accu_Position']

        self.df['TakeProfit_Signal'] = 0
        take_profit_condition = ((self.df['Accu_Position'] == 1) & (self.df['PriceChange'] >= self.take_profit)) | ((self.df['Accu_Position'] == -1) & (self.df['PriceChange'] <= -self.take_profit))
        self.df.loc[take_profit_condition, 'TakeProfit_Signal'] = -self.df['Accu_Position']

        self.df['Signal'] = self.df[['Buy_Signal', 'Sell_Signal', 'StopLoss_Signal', 'TakeProfit_Signal']].sum(axis=1)
        self.df['Position'] += self.df['Signal']

        num_buy_signals = self.df['Buy_Signal'].sum()
        num_sell_signals = self.df['Sell_Signal'].sum()
        num_take_profit_signals = self.df['TakeProfit_Signal'].sum()
        num_stop_loss_signals = self.df['StopLoss_Signal'].sum()

        print('Number of Buy Signals:', num_buy_signals)
        print('Number of Sell Signals:', num_sell_signals)
        print('Number of Take Profit Signals:', num_take_profit_signals)
        print('Number of Stop Loss Signals:', num_stop_loss_signals)
        print('Number of Stop Loss Signals:', num_stop_loss_signals)
        print(self.df['Accu_Position'])

    def calculate_pnl(self):
        self.df['PnL'] = self.df['Close'] * self.df['Position']
        self.df['AccuPnl'] = self.df['PnL'] + self.df['PnL'].shift()
        print('Total PnL:', self.df['PnL'].sum())


    def apply_strategy(self):
        self.calculate_moving_average()
        self.calculate_deviation()
        self.generate_signals()
        self.calculate_pnl()
        return self.df

strategy = MovingAverageStrategy(df, window_size=200, buy_threshold=-0.0350, sell_threshold=0.0350, stop_loss=0.0020, take_profit=0.0050)
df = strategy.apply_strategy()

# # Plotting the equity
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plt.plot(df['Close'], label='Equity')
plt.plot(df['MovingAverage'], label='MovingAverage')

# # Plotting the buy and sell points
buy_points = df[df['Buy_Signal'] != 0]
sell_points = df[df['Sell_Signal'] != 0]
StopLoss_points = df[df['StopLoss_Signal'] != 0]
TakeProfit_points = df[df['TakeProfit_Signal'] != 0]

plt.scatter(buy_points.index, buy_points['Close'], color='green', label='Buy')
plt.scatter(sell_points.index, sell_points['Close'], color='red', label='Sell')
plt.scatter(StopLoss_points.index, StopLoss_points['Close'], color='blue', label='StopLoss')
plt.scatter(TakeProfit_points.index, TakeProfit_points['Close'], color='orange', label='TakeProfit')

plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Equity')
plt.title('Equity and Buy/Sell Points')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

However for buy signal generating part:

self.df['Buy_Condition'] = (self.df['Deviation'] <= self.buy_threshold) & (self.df['Accu_Position'] == 0)

when removing the second condition after "&" result stays exactly the same...there is totally no stop loss or take profit signals either. Would any kind-hearted coder help enlighten me on this please...?

Tried consulting to Cursor but problem seems to be remaining.

Comment: Maybe `self.df['Accu_Position']` is always equal to 0? Or `self.def['Deviation'] <= self.buy_threshold` is always false so that the second condition is irrelevant?

Comment: Are you sure you really want to use `&` that does a [bitwise and](https://realpython.com/python-bitwise-operators/#bitwise-and) operation  and not use `and` that does a [logical and](https://realpython.com/python-and-operator/) operation?